# screwed up my code, local storage worked, now it doesnt again, no idea what changed

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to set local storage of best game times, so I created an empty array `gBestScores` and compared the value of the last best score to the current one,
and depending on the result I either push it or not to the array.

The local storage supposed to save it. The saving doesn't happen and the array stays empty. The `currScore` is showing the correct clock content.
`lastBestScore` is undefined. Iv'e tried hard coding 2 start times to the -1 won't come back as unidentified, that didn't work, and it work beforehand without doing that

the comparison and the storage worked, i have no idea what i changed, ctrl-Z failed to save me,
hope you can.

second update:
array gets overwritten to nothing even with hardcoded values, no idea what causes this

`var gBestScores =[]`

in the init i have:

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("scores");
    gBestScores = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
    bestScore.innerHTML = gBestScores[gBestScores.length - 1]
```

the rest of it:

```
function checkGameStatus() {
    // debugger
    var currScore = result.innerHTML
    var lastBestScore = gBestScores[gBestScores.length-1]
    if ((gLevel.SIZE ** 2 - gLevel.MINES) === gGame.shownCount && gLevel.MINES === gGame.markedCount) {
        gElBtn.innerHTML = WIN
        gGame.isOn = true
        stopwatch.stop()
        if (currScore > lastBestScore) {
            gBestScores.push(currScore)
        }
    }
    else if (gGame.isOn === true) {
        gElBtn.innerHTML = SAD
        stopwatch.stop()
        if (currScore > lastBestScore) {
            gBestScores.push(currScore) 
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("scores", JSON.stringify(gBestScores));
    bestScore.innerHTML = lastBestScore
}
```

Comment: not really an answer to your original problem: start using git, even when you only use it locally you easily get a longer history ("undo buffer") than your editor provides

Comment: about to start learning it, however this doesnt help me atm.. why isnt the array being filled?

Comment: checkGameStatus has too may undefined things for it to be useful.  What do you do if local storage isn't or hasn't been set?

Comment: i have no idea, when it worked it just pushed the first timer that was played, like i sayed i tried hard coding 2 values to the empty array for , didnt help

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code doesn't manage all use cases, so, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, depending on the values stored in localStorage and the value of currScore

Try this :

In the init :

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("scores")
var gBestScores = [] // initialize gBestScores
if(retrievedData){ // check your localStorage
    gBestScores = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
    bestScore.innerHTML = gBestScores[gBestScores.length - 1]
}
```

In the function checkGameStatus :

```
function checkGameStatus() {
    // debugger
    var currScore = parseInt(result.innerHTML) // parse the current score to Int (or float if you want)
    var lastBestScore = gBestScores.length > 0 ? gBestScores[gBestScores.length-1] : 0 // check if gBestScores is empty
    if ((gLevel.SIZE ** 2 - gLevel.MINES) === gGame.shownCount && gLevel.MINES === gGame.markedCount) {
        gElBtn.innerHTML = WIN
        gGame.isOn = true
        stopwatch.stop()
        if (currScore > lastBestScore) {
            lastBestScore = currScore // assign the current score to lastBestScore
            gBestScores.push(currScore)
        }
    }
    else if (gGame.isOn === true) {
        gElBtn.innerHTML = SAD
        stopwatch.stop()
        if (currScore > lastBestScore) {
            lastBestScore = currScore // assign the current score to lastBestScore
            gBestScores.push(currScore) 
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("scores", JSON.stringify(gBestScores));
    bestScore.innerHTML = lastBestScore
}
```